# Apache Camel - Spring rest endpoint reference

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-camel

I have an application using camel rest component. Originally, I use camel version v2.17.0 and every rest endpoint returns http return code 200 when call.

One day when I update my application's camel version to v2.18.0 (without any other change), all rest endpoint returns http return code 404 when call. The same case happens for v2.18.4 and v2.19.0.

I doubt whether there is a change in rest endpoint path reference via Spring. Is anyone know how to correct my setup? The workaround I am using is to move hardcode String back to Spring which does not fit my intention.

**Spring setup for Rest Service**

```
<endpoint id="httpAppRouteBuildRemainPath" uri="#{commonUtilService.getEpUtil().getHTTPAppJsonBuildRemainPath()}" />
<endpoint id="httpSysRouteBuildRemainPath" uri="#{commonUtilService.getEpUtil().getHTTPSysJsonBuildRemainPath()}" />
<endpoint id="httpJsonBuildManagementRouteEndPoint" uri="#{commonUtilService.getEpUtil().getHTTPJsonBuildManagementRouteEndpointPath()}" />

<rest path="#commonUtilService.getEpUtil().getHTTPJsonManagementRestPath()">
        <put uri="ref:httpAppRouteBuildRemainPath" id="appHttpRouteReceiver">
                <to uri="ref:httpJsonBuildManagementRouteEndPoint"/>
        </put>
        <put uri="ref:httpSysRouteBuildRemainPath" id="sysHttpRouteReceiver">
                <to uri="ref:httpJsonBuildManagementRouteEndPoint"/>
        </put>
</rest>
```

**Java Setup**

```
public String getHTTPJsonManagementRestPath() {
        return "/worker/json";
}

public String getHTTPAppJsonBuildRemainPath() {
        return "/app/build";
}

public String getHTTPSysJsonBuildRemainPath() {
        return "/sys/build";
}
```

**Test Result**

Under camel version v2.17.0

> Jun 07, 2017 11:10:16 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
>
> INFO: 2017-06-07 11:10:16 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - 9395 PUT
>   /worker/json/app/build - **200** 40 124 35 http://localhost:9395        - -

Under camel version v2.18.0

> Jun 07, 2017 11:11:33 AM org.restlet.routing.Template getRegexPattern
>
> WARNING: Empty pattern variables are not allowed : null
>   Jun 07, 2017 11:11:33 AM org.restlet.routing.Template getRegexPattern
>
> WARNING: Empty pattern variables are not allowed : null
>   Jun 07, 2017 11:11:33 AM org.restlet.routing.Template getRegexPattern
>
> WARNING: Empty pattern variables are not allowed : null
>   Jun 07, 2017 11:11:33 AM org.restlet.routing.Template getRegexPattern
>
> WARNING: Empty pattern variables are not allowed : null
>   Jun 07, 2017 11:11:33 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
>
> INFO: 2017-06-07 11:11:33 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - 9395 PUT /worker/json/app/build - **404** 439 124 12 http://localhost:9395        - -

---

**Update**

I change the spring setup to

```
<rest path="/worker/json">
    <put uri="/app/build" id="appHttpRouteReceiver">
        <to uri="ref:httpJsonBuildManagementRouteEndPoint"/>
    </put>
    <put uri="ref:httpSysRouteBuildRemainPath" id="sysHttpRouteReceiver">
        <to uri="ref:httpJsonBuildManagementRouteEndPoint"/>
    </put>
</rest>
```

**Test result**

Under camel version v2.18.0

> Jun 26, 2017 10:12:50 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
>
> INFO: 2017-06-26   10:12:50    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -   -   9395    PUT /worker/json/**ref:httpSysRouteBuildRemainPath**    -   **200** 61  46  39  http://localhost:9395   -   -
>
> Jun 26, 2017 10:14:54 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
>
> INFO: 2017-06-26   10:14:54    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -   -   9395    PUT /worker/json/**app/build**  -   **200** 61  40  18  http://localhost:9395   Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1  -
>
> Jun 26, 2017 10:18:53 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
>
> INFO: 2017-06-26   10:18:53    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -   -   9395    PUT /worker/json/**sys/build**  -   **404** 439 40  6   http://localhost:9395   Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1  -

Comment: You have 2 x put which would end up with the same path, you should use different paths or only 1 put

Comment: @ClausIbsen Looks like the rest endpoint use `ref:httpSysRouteBuildRemainPath` as path instead of looking up endpoint reference. Is there any method I can do to set the value from Java side?

Comment: Use `{{xxx}}` for property placeholders: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks, but property placeholders does not fit my purpose. It works when I was original set second put uri as `<post uri="#{commonUtilService.getEpUtil().getAdminHTTPSysJsonBuildRemainPath()}" id="admin_sysHttpSysJson_receiver">`, but not work when I extract it as endpoint reference

Answer (score -1):

I logged a ticket to look into this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11414